# for loop being ignored because of initial condition does not satisfy

Tags: loops, for-loop, conditional-statements, defined

I am very new to C++ and as a starter project I decided to convert a python code I wrote earlier to C++. So far it has been going good but it looks like I am stuck in this position. Basically, I want to write a for loop that prints cointosses based on how many flips the user inputted. However, when running the code it totally ignores the for loop because it does not satisfy the condition. My question is what condition might that be and what can I do to resolve this issue. thx!

I already tried changing the arguments that are fed in the for loop between the brackets but I am very clueless as I am not experienced with C++.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    std::string heads = "Heads";
    std::string tails = "Tails";
    int numHeads = 0;
    int numTails = 0;
    int flips = 0;
    printf("How many flips do you want to toss?: ");
    std::cin >> flips;

    int RandIndex = rand() % 2;
    std::string cointoss[2] = { heads, tails };

    for (flips = 0; flips; flips++)
        std::cout << cointoss[RandIndex];
    return;



}
```

I am expecting my code to print specific amount of flips which is being inputted by the user.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. You do `cin >> flips`, then overwrite that with `flips = 0` under that. Are you intending to do something like `for(int i = 0; i < flips; i++) { . . .`?

Comment: I originally wanted to define that variable to an input just like python: flips = int(input("blah"))